# Breadcrumb Path Disappearing (temporarily) after Cron

Tags: cron, breadcrumbs

This is a problem that's been bugging me for a while. I am using a book structure to generate my breadcrumbs, but it seems that when I first load a page, only the homepage and title of the page itself loads in the breadcrumbs. However, once I refresh the page the rest of the path will show up.

See this image for an example of what I'm talking about: [image: http://i.imgur.com/PqnHP.gif]

The breadcrumb trail on the top is the initial page load, and the one underneath it is when the page has been viewed at least once.

It seems that the paths all get reset whenever the cron is run. What exactly is going on?